# Starting an embedded Jetty server as a background process

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I have a Spring application and have used Tomcat to develop it and run it on the server. I was quite frustrated with deploy->undeploy-->deploy again-->.. development process, so I decided to switch to embedded Jetty. So basically now I have just a single Java class that's responsible for starting my server:

```
public class MainServer {

private Server start() throws Exception {
    Server jetty = new Server();
    String[] configFiles = { "WebContent/WEB-INF/jetty.xml" };
    for (String configFile : configFiles) {
        XmlConfiguration configuration = new XmlConfiguration(new File(configFile).toURI().toURL());
        configuration.configure(jetty);
    }

    WebAppContext appContext = new WebAppContext();
    File warPath = new File("WebContent");
    appContext.setWar(warPath.getAbsolutePath());
    appContext.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    appContext.setContextPath("/4d");
    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { appContext, new DefaultHandler() });
    jetty.setHandler(handlers);

    jetty.start();
    jetty.join();
    return jetty;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new MainServer().start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

This is perfect for developing as it allows hotswapping and seems to be faster. However, I would also like to deploy this setting to my server later on. What is the best way to start this server and running it in the background (like Tomcat startup.sh)? How should I call this MainServer class?

Comment: Ok, so what I ended up doing is to give up on starting the server by code myself, and instead, I set up Maven to handle all my packaging and building. So at least now it's not that painful to deploy the application to production server. I might look into that nohup later on, as there are quite many topics about it already.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned startup.sh, so I suppose your server is unix like. Then consider using [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) command:

```
nohup java [options] MainServer > nohup.out &
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing an initscript (look for /etc/init.d/skeleton as a starting point) using [start-stop-daemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/de/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html). Going with the standard takes some time but pays off later.

We are using embedded jetty and init scripts for years now. It has never let us down.